# not able register my model to wagtail admin using wagtail_hooks.py

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

wagtail 4.1 It seems that I did everything as stated in the documentation, but my models do not appear in the admin panel.[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE5DM.png)

my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
cover_photo = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True, blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)

panels = [
    FieldPanel('title'),
    FieldPanel('author'),
    FieldPanel('cover_photo')
]
```

my wagtail_hooks.py

```
 class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    menu_label = 'Book'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'  # change as required
    menu_order = 201  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = True  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = True # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ('title', 'author')
    list_filter = ('author',)
    search_fields = ('title', 'author')


# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(BookAdmin)
```

I also registered my applications

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    "news",
    "app",
    "wagtail.contrib.modeladmin",
]
```

what can i miss?

Comment: This works for me when I add the 'news' app to a newly-created Wagtail 4.1 project. Just to confirm - you've set `add_to_settings_menu = True`, so you're looking under the Settings submenu for the Book item, right?

Comment: the solution was that it was necessary to move the files with the model into a separate application, and not leave them in the root. Wagtail did not give errors, but it also did not create tables in the database.

Comment: Not sure I understand - your screenshot shows models.py in the news app, not in the project root. Glad you fixed it, anyway!

Comment: i also changed db. deleted all migrations and migrate to pgsql from sqldblight

Comment: i mean i created django models file in the same dir with settings